# Android Gps app not as accurate as google maps app

Tags: android, gps, location, maps

i am developing an app that needs to know your location at all times. I understand that the location accuracy is not perfect and i believe ive tried everything i found in google developers help, stackoverflow, etc...

The problem i have is the following:
In some places the location i get is not as accurate as the one you would get using google maps. I use both the network provider and the gps provider to updated locations and i filter them to keep the most accurate one (using the code provided in google developers).

In most places the accuracy will be great, near pefect, but in some areas i get a terrible accuracy, up to 100meters difference between actual location and the provided from gps/network.

Ill post the code below and i would like to know if there is something else i can do to improve the accuracy.

```
private void setLocationListener() {
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if(isBetterLocation(location,miLocation)) {
                miLocation=location;
                doStuff(location);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity2.this,"Ha desactivado el gps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MapActivity2.this.finish();

        }


    };
    checkCallingPermission(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}


protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }
//        if (location.getAccuracy()>15) return false;

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TIEMPO_LOC;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TIEMPO_LOC;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}

private void doStuff(Location location) {
    if (myMarker != null) miMarker.remove();
    int iconResource = getResources().getIdentifier("iconomylocation", "drawable", getPackageName());
    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title("Our location")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResource)));
}
```

TIEMPO_LOC is 1000; (1 second) I cannot really afford to refresh slower.

Edit: Oh forgot to mention, i am from spain (there shouldnt be any offset like that China problem that happened to other users).

Comment: did you try the FusedLocationProvider (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) that is part of the Google Play Services? I'm pretty sure GMaps uses that.

Comment: Just finished testing your suggestion and it seems it has improved in the areas it was not working properly. Thanks!